# Reading from Infinispan cache goes into infinite loop

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi, infinispan

I am using Nifi to create data flow pipeline where I use Infinispan a a cache server But when I use executescript with Groovy script , it goes on infinite loop and open many socket connections. I have tried to close the same but still it opens many connections and then it throws

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

By following below link I changed the registry
https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP06_KnowledgeWithSidebarTroubleshoot?id=kA280000000PEE1CAO&popup=false&lang=en_US

Then checked the open connections with `netstat -n` I opens 65534 because of the above settings.

Below is the groovy script to read from Infinispan cache

```
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCache;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

def cacheName = "mycache"

def configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.addServer().host("localhost").port(11322).build();

def cacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(configuration)

RemoteCache cacheA = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName)

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
key = flowFile.getAttribute('key')
id = flowFile.getAttribute('id')
jsonFromCache = cacheA.get(key + "_" + id);
if(cacheA != null) {
cacheA.stop()
}
if(cacheManager != null) {
cacheManager.stop()
}

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream ->
  outputStream.write(jsonFromCache.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as OutputStreamCallback)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Have you tried finispan?  (Sorry...  I couldn't resist.)

Comment: @user2478398 Was anything wrong in my question?

Comment: Absolutely not.  I was just being immature (hence the sorry).  If I knew any of the libraries here well enough to help I would have, but I'm afraid I don't.

Comment: You are opening connection to cache before getting file from session. You are opening connection and at this line just exits script without closing it: `if(!flowFile) return`

Comment: BTW, it's possible to handle processor start and stop to make cache connection once per processor.

Comment: @daggett how to do that?

Comment: @daggett Yes you are right. I was opening connection to cache before getting file from session. This solved.Thanks. I want to know more about this "it's possible to handle processor start and stop to make cache connection once per processor."

Comment: Use executegroovyscript. Then this feature will be available. Example you can find here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html

Comment: @daggett Thanks alot. I did it with stop start events. Above comments should be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening connection to cache before getting file from session.

So, you are opening connection and at the following line just exits script without closing it:

```
if(!flowFile) return
```

Another point: 
you can use ExecuteGroovyScript processor. Then processor start & stop could be managed. Example you can find here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

class Const{
  static Date startTime = null;
  static AtomicLong triggerCount = null;
}

static onStart(ProcessContext context){
  Const.startTime = new Date()
  Const.triggerCount = new AtomicLong(0)
  println "onStart $context ${Const.startTime}"
}

static onStop(ProcessContext context){
  def alive = (System.currentTimeMillis() - Const.startTime.getTime()) / 1000
  println "onStop $context executed ${ Const.triggerCount } times during ${ alive } seconds"
}

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile)return
flowFile.'trigger.count' = Const.triggerCount.incrementAndGet()
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```